# Having issues with using dual monitor with ubuntu 18.4

Tags: 18.04

I have tried all available solutions on stackExchange and other platform but nothing seems to work. I really need to be able to share my monitor with my ubuntu desktop.

My hardware is core i5 Intel, Ram 16GiB, OS Linux. I tried the following but to no avail: changing the Gnome GUI to KDE, and other alternative GUI but to no avail. I also tried to update software. Tried to update the OS kernel; Tried different HDMI cables; Research and review over 20 different online solution

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Add info about your hardware and about what are all available solutions you have tried.

Comment: If we are talking about displays, then Graphic adapter info is essential. https://www.binarytides.com/linux-get-gpu-information/

Comment: @Gryu  My hardware is: Core i5 Intel, Ram 16GiB, Linux OS.                                                                                                           I tried the following but to no avail: Change the Gnome GUI to KDE and other alternative GUI but to no avail; Tried to update the OS kernel; Tried different HDMI cables; Research and review over 20 different online solutions

Comment: @Gryu I you saying I should probably install a new Graphic Adapter to enable this to work? I have not tried that anyways. Thanks.

Comment: You could use commands to show info about your grafic adapter. It could be helpful. Maybe there are similar issues with hardware as yours. Maybe there is an issue with drivers. Do you have Intel, Radeon, Nvidia graphic card? What is a model?